# How to I get a string from an array element found with .select without brackets in ruby?

Tags: arrays, regex, ruby, string

Right now I'm having major difficulty finding a way to get a string from an array element without brackets.

I'm using .select to find a specific element in the array of strings I'm using, but when I try to print the variable I store the result to, it ends up also storing the brackets as well. I've tried numerous things, such as using .to_s and .join(''), but unforunately

```
      found=file_arr.select {|str| str=~/\A#{find_x} #{y}/}
      if visited.include?("#{found}") == false
         #Do this
      end
```

What I want to get is 
#String_here
But what I'm getting instead is
[\"#String_here\n\"]

Comment: The result that select gives you, may not be the one you need as argument for `include`; `['found', 'not found'].select { |x| x =~ /\w/ }.to_s` would give you an array as String `"[\"found\", \"not found\"]"`, using `join` would give you the result as concatenated `"foundnot found"`.

Comment: This smells like an XY problem. What is the actual thing you want to do? `File.open(...) { |f| f.each_line.grep(...) ... }` might suit you better...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Enumerable#select](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-select) will *return an array containing all elements of enum for which the given block returns a true value*.

[Enumerable#find](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-find) will *return the first for which block is not false*.

So in your case, you can use find instead:

```
found = file_arr.find { |str| str =~ /\A#{find_x} #{y}/ }
```

---

Notice your condition can be more understandable with `unless`:

```
do_something unless visited.include?("#{found}")
```